# Writing a run-length encoding for a string length 64 using recursion (& no loops) in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, run-length-encoding

I have to write a function that takes in a 64 character input string of 0's and 1's and have it return the run-length encoding for that string, but I do not think I have even started this correctly at all...

```
def compress(s):
''' takes a binary string s of length less than or equal to 64 as input
and returns another binary string as output. Output binary string will be
a run-length encoding of the input string.
'''
listS = list(s)
if s == "":
    return 0
else:
    listS[0] = "0"
    listS[8] = "1"
    listS[16] = "0"
    listS[24] = "1"
    listS[32] = "0"
    listS[40] = "1"
    listS[48] = "0"
    listS[56] = "1"

    newSomething = helper1(s)

    return ''.join(listS)
```

I'm not quite sure if the above is even correct, but this and the helper function below are all that I have so far. I can not figure out how to create a run-length encoding string for a given binary string s...

I am not sure if this function below is helpful but it was meant as a start to convert the number of consecutive 0's or 1's into an integer and then is returned back as the number in binary coding.

```
def helper1(s):
    '''takes in string and returns 0... but stores newString which
    shows string for binary of sum of consecutive numbers
    '''
    sum = 0
    listS = list(s)
    if len(s) < 2:
        return sum
    elif listS[0] == listS[1]:
        sum += 1
        newString = numToBinary(sum)
        return helper1(s[1:])
    elif listS[0] != listS[1]:
        sum = 0
        return helper1(s[1:])
```

Thinking about it now, I don't even think any part of my compress(s) function is correct as it stands above.

We have not yet learned for or while loops so they can not be used here, we've focused on recursion though. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Teaching recursion before loops in Python isn't the greatest idea, as recursion is a bit of a second-class citizen in Python...

Comment: Looping over data using recursion makes no sense at all.. what are you going to do, call the function for each next byte you process? For any real data processing that's a one-way trip to a stack overflow.